# Google Play Developer API defer request error - The desired expiry time for the subscription is not valid

Tags: google-api-java-client, android-inapp-purchase

I am trying to defer billing of an in-app purchase in my app. But every time I get the following error

```
    Exception was thrown while updating 
    listingcom.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 
    400 Bad Request
     {
       "code" : 400,
       "errors" : [ {
       "domain" : "androidpublisher",
       "message" : "The desired expiry time for the subscription is not 
       valid.",
       "reason" : "subscriptionDeferInvalidTime"
       } ],
      "message" : "The desired expiry time for the subscription is not valid."
     }
```

I have written the following code for the request. I am sure the variables like package name subscriptionID and subscriptionToken are correct because purchases.get call works.
Variable expirytime is saved from previous get call response.

```
class DeferBilling extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME),
                    "ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME cannot be null or empty!");

            // Create the API service.
            final AndroidPublisher service = AndroidPublisherHelper.init(
                    ApplicationConfig.APPLICATION_NAME, ApplicationConfig.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, getBaseContext());
            final AndroidPublisher.Purchases purchases = service.purchases();
            SubscriptionPurchasesDeferRequest request = new SubscriptionPurchasesDeferRequest();
            SubscriptionDeferralInfo info = new SubscriptionDeferralInfo();
            long desiredTime = expiryTime + 10*60*1000;
            long expectedTime = expiryTime;
            info.setDesiredExpiryTimeMillis(desiredTime);
            info.setExpectedExpiryTimeMillis(expectedTime);
            request.setDeferralInfo(sdi);
            SubscriptionPurchasesDeferResponse response = purchases.subscriptions().defer(ApplicationConfig.PACKAGE_NAME,GlobalClass.subscriptionID,
                    GlobalClass.subscriptionToken,request).execute();
            System.out.println(response);
            return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown" + e.toString());
            return "";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that I was calculating desiredTime by adding only 10 minutes, whereas it is necessary to defer billing by some days. When I deferred billing by 30 days , it worked.

Comment: Thanks for that. That's weird, no info about that in Google docs only: "The desired next expiry time to assign to the subscription, in milliseconds since the Epoch. The given time must be later/greater than the current expiry time for the subscription."

Answer (score 0):

See Document In [Defer billing for a subscriber](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#defer).
The desiredExpiryTimeMillis must Greater than 1 day and less than 1 year.